# Check if div has keyboard focus

Tags: jquery, keyboard, focus, mouse

I have a div which auto hides 5 seconds after the mouse leaves the area. I want to prevent this hiding if any element within the div has keyboard focus and re-enable if the user tabs out. This is my code

```
delayedRollUp = function() {
    if ( !$metaArea.hasClass('active') ) {
        var timeout = setTimeout(function(){
            animateRollUp( $metaTab );
        }, 5000 );
        $metaArea.data('timeout', timeout);
    }
};

// Make the meta boxes dissapear on mouse leave
$metaArea.mouseenter( function(){
    clearTimeout($(this).data('timeout'));
}).mouseleave(function(){
    delayedRollUp();
}).focusin( function(){
    $metaArea.addClass('active');
}).focusout(function(){
    $metaArea.removeClass('active');
});
```

I can see the problem is that both mouse and keyboard events are not taking each other into account. I need a conditional check, something like `hasMouseFocus` and `hasKeyboardFocus` so that I can prevent `setTimeout()` from being called, but I cannot find any methods like those in the docs.

Updated the code to add an active class to the `$metaArea`. This partly works in that it doesn't hide if clicking on an element, but tabbing between elements is causing the timeout to be reset.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You should provide a jsfiddle imo

Comment: @A.Wolff I would like to but for some reason I just cannot get jQuery to work in my fiddles. At the moment I'm having to write the js file, save and reload it into the browser.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if an input element has focus with the `:focus` selector.

`// Returns number of elements currently focused inside #container` (0 or 1)
`$('#container input:focus').length`

Reference

- https://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/

Comment: The link you provided is for the `.focus()` event, not the `:focus` selector. Unfortunately google strips the leading colon.

Comment: I found it. Problem is it didn't work, or perhaps I used it wrong. Managed to solve half the problem by adding a class to the clickable tab. Now I'm trying to work out the tabbing out and into a hidden element.